# merging fields from pivot table to prep mail merge

Tags: vba, excel

I am prepping a mail merge to notify interested parties of entities that there has been an address change. I extracted all information fine and have it in Excel. The problem is, there is a ton is data and some emails have multiple entities. I have attached an example of this.

Is there anyway to get the email and corresponding entities in cells right next to each other? (total of 2 cells for each set)

i.e. from
 [image: example 1]
 TO
[image: example 2].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Sum()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, size As Integer, Bound As Integer: size = 0
Dim lRow As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim arr() As Variant, arr2() As Variant
Dim data As String

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Adjust

lRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lRow
    If sht.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        ReDim Preserve arr(size)
        arr(size) = i
        size = size + 1
    End If
Next
arr2 = sht.Range("A1:B" & lRow)
sht.Range("A1:B" & lRow).Columns.Clear
For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
    If i + 1 > UBound(arr) Then
        Bound = lRow
    Else
        Bound = arr(i + 1) - 1
    End If
    For j = arr(i) To Bound
        If j = Bound Then
            data = data & arr2(j, 2)
        Else
            data = data & arr2(j, 2) & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next j
    sht.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = arr2(arr(i), 1)
    sht.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = data
    data = ""
Next i
End Sub
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

So what it does basically is, that i go trough Col A and get the rows of the emails. Then it store the data in an array and deletes the content of the columns. Finally it will then go trough the array (it uses the first array to get the index of the second array) and give out the desired format.

Comment: I added this macro to the workbook and it worked FLAWLESSLY. Thank you so much for the help!